# How to solve the Pandas issue related to Series.fillna()?

Tags: python, pandas

I just upgrade from Pandas 0.11 to 0.13.0rc1. The upgration caused one error related to Series.fillna().

```
>>> df
                   sales  net_pft
STK_ID RPT_Date                  
600809 20060331   5.8951   1.1241
       20060630   8.3031   1.5464
       20060930  11.9084   2.2990
       20061231      NaN   2.6060
       20070331   5.9129   1.3334

[5 rows x 2 columns]
>>> type(df['sales'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> df['sales'] = df['sales'].fillna(df['net_pft'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1912, in fillna
    obj.fillna(v, inplace=True)
AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'fillna'
>>>
```

Why `df['sales']` become `'numpy.float64'` object when it is used in `fillna()` ? How to correctly do "fill the NaN of one column with the other column's value" ?

Comment: There was a recent discussion on this, and it is fixed in pandas master: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5703

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a recent discussion on this, and it is fixed in pandas master: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5703 (after the release of 0.13rc1, so it will be fixed in final 0.13).

Note: the behaviour changed! This was not supported behaviour in pandas <= 0.12, as @behzad.nouri points out (using a Series as input to `fillna`). However it did work but was apparantly based on the location, which was wrong. But as long as both serieses (`df['sales']` and `df['net_pft']` in you case) have the same index, this will not matter.
In pandas 0.13, it will be supported but based on the index of the Series. See comment here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5703#issuecomment-30663525

Answer (score 1):

it seems more like what you are trying to do is:

```
idx = df['sales'].isnull( )
df['sales'][ idx ] = df['net_pft'][ idx ]
```

because what you are providing as `value` argument to `fillna` is a series, the code goes into the bellow branch which calls `fillna` for every index item of the provided series. If `self` was a DataFrame this would have worked correctly, that is it would `fillna` each column using the provided series, but since `self` here is a Series it will break.

As in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) to `fillna` a DataFrame the parameter value can be

> alternately a dict of values specifying which value to use for each column (columns not in the dict will not be filled).

from the source code below, if `value` is a Series it will work the same way as a dict using the Series' index as keys to `fillna` corresponding columns.

```
    else:   # value is not None
        if method is not None:
            raise ValueError('cannot specify both a fill method and value')

        if len(self._get_axis(axis)) == 0:
            return self
        if isinstance(value, (dict, com.ABCSeries)):
            if axis == 1:
                raise NotImplementedError('Currently only can fill '
                                          'with dict/Series column '
                                          'by column')

            result = self if inplace else self.copy()
            for k, v in compat.iteritems(value):
                if k not in result:
                    continue
                obj = result[k]
                obj.fillna(v, inplace=True)
            return result
        else:
            new_data = self._data.fillna(value, inplace=inplace,
                                         downcast=downcast)
```

Comment: note, it works fine for 0.12, so I'm not sure whether it's not a bug

Comment: You are right the usage of Series was not supported, although it did work (the bug the OP saw was introduced during development of 0.13), and the documentation you cite is for a DataFrame, not a Series (the OP has a Series). But starting from 0.13 the usage of a Series will be supported, and for a DataFrame work as you explained.

Comment: @joris Series documentation for 0.13 which was the OP question, is the same as the one i have linked above( see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna) )

Comment: It changed only this night ..., so tomorrow after following nightly build it will be different: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/2792e2d22ca498da7126cfc03152fa6c0617b1ab. But indeed, for 0.13 it is the same docs for Series and DataFrame, so you are right. They were only not really updated for the Series case.